# Adding two values in column A for different rows given a condition that their values in column B is similar in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my first question on StackOverflow. If there is anything wrong with the formatting, please do let me know as I'm still not familiar with it.

I'm having trouble with adding two values from different columns given a certain condition. Here is the table

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LYiy.png)

I would like to add the valuation price if they are in the same quarter. E.g quarter = '20173'. Which will return 200,000 + 150,000 = 350,000. If there is only one value for one quarter, I'd like it to display just that value, e.g quarter = '20192' which returns 100,000.

I've tried this out

```
A = raw_data['QUARTER'].unique()
values = np.array(A)
raw_data.loc[(raw_data['QUARTER'] == values[i] ), 'Valuation price'].sum()
```

which returns the error below

> only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would you like to have an extra column in your current dataframe with the result? Or is the answer below what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, the answer below is what I'm looking for. How do I close this question or mark it as answered?

Comment: You can click on the "tick" next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be an answer for your question.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'size': [623, 623, 623, 640], 'value': [13, 10, 16, 4],
        'quarter': [20144, 20152, 20152, 19903], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = df.groupby('quarter').sum()['value']
```

where `df`:

```
   size  value  quarter name
0   623     13    20144    a
1   623     10    20152    b
2   623     16    20152    c
3   640      4    19903    d
```

and `result`:

```
quarter
19903     4
20144    13
20152    26
Name: value, dtype: int64
```